# Converting native JS to angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular function which takes credentials form a JSON file which will be used for users to sign into the site. I am getting slightly confused converting my Native JS to angular. Below I have provided a snippet of my code

I seem to getting the error 'user' not defined

Native JS

```
if (text1 == users[0] && text2 == pwd[0]) {
    location.href = "profile-01-home.html";
} else if (text1 == users[1] && text2 == pwd[1]) {
    location.href = "profile-02-home.html";
} else {
    location.href = "login.html";
}
```

Angular JS

```
  .controller('logCtrl', ['$scope', 'loginService', function($scope, loginService, $timeout, $window, $location) {

  var promise = loginService.getuser();
  promise.then(function (data){
      $scope.users = data.users;
  });

  if ($scope.username == $scope.users[0] && $scope.password == $scope.users[0].password) {
    $location.path('/profile-01');
  } else if ($scope.username == $scope.users[1] && $scope.password == $scope.users[1].password)  {
    $location.path('/profile-02');
  } else if ($scope.username == $scope.users[2] && $scope.password == $scope.users[2].password) {
    $location.path('/profile-03');
  } else if ($scope.username == $scope.users[3] && $scope.password == $scope.users[3].password) {
    $location.path('/profile-04');
  } else if ($scope.username == $scope.users[4] && $scope.password == $scope.users[4].password) {
    $location.path('/profile-05');
  } else {
    $location.path('/login');
  }
```

}])

Answer (score 0):

It could become something like this:

```
if (text1 == users[0] && text2 == pwd[0]) {
    $location.path('/profile-01-home').replace();
} else if (text1 == users[1] && text2 == pwd[1]) {
    $location.path('/profile-02-home').replace();
} else {
    $location.path('/login').replace();
}
```

Though, be warne Angular 1 differs a lot from Angular 2, for example about the routing system (which handles location handinng).
So, I suggest you to first decide which platform you do prefer (angular.1 being simpler, angular.2 being the future), and the taking a tutorial... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a slash to your paths.

Yours: `$location.path('profile-05')`

Correct: `$location.path('/profile-05')`

It appears that you also have an error in your querySelector invocations. If you are trying to fetch elements by class name, it should have a period in front of it. If it is an id, an octothorp (hashtag).

`document.querySelector('.className')`
`document.querySelector('#idName')`

And as mentioned, you should definitely register your variables to your model using ng-model.

`<input data-ng-model='$scope.variableName'>`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using

```
var username = angular.element(document.querySelector('username')).value;
var password = angular.element(document.querySelector('password')).value;
```

Instead use `ng-model` in your templates and bind directly to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `user` value is on `$scope`. Try using `$scope.user[0]` instead of `user[0]`.

Also `$location.path()` expects a url. You are using `$location.path('profile-02');` which is incorrect. The correct usage is `$location.path('/profile-02');`

Answer (score 0):

Problamatic is :

```
 var username = angular.element(document.querySelector('username')).value;
     var password = angular.element(document.querySelector('password')).value;
```

controller can be run before DOM element exists.
Get value from ng-model, or wrap this using directive

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general considerations: When you are calling the function to get user you do not need to store the promise in a variable. If the function needs to be called within the controller or by a DOM element store on load look over ng-init. You do not need to query for field input, instead use ng-model and map to scope (look at this on your own). Regarding passwords I included a great example. Remember users can see scope in chrome debug tools etc. I also recommend using objects and json like follows:

```
$scope.data = {};

loginService.getuser()
  .then(function (data){
  $scope.data = data;
});
```

// Then interact with user

$scope.data.user...

example of handling password [password example](https://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/76E4S/)

Comment: This function is using a JSON file hence the promise

Comment: I assumed you were using $q in your service so that it is non blocking. If you are not you need to look a $q and async in angular. There should be no difference between a file or a restful http service.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<input ng-model="$scope.username" id="username" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
```

Will be like this:

```
<input ng-model="username" id="username" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
```

Instead of trying to assign values to element from your angular controller using element id, bind those elements with a model or a value associated with scope, and then directly use it from View template.

You need to understand that Angular js is bit different from libraries like jQuery

For example, to change html of a div with id "username" in jQuery, we will do:

```
$('#username').html('New Value')
```

Now, if we have something similar in Angular, we just need to bind the variable from controller in template.

For example this in our Controller:

```
//Other Controller Code
$scope.user = {'username': "NewBoy", 'firstName': "new", 'lastname': "Boy"};
```

Then we can do following in controller:

```
<div>
Hello {{user.firstName}}, welcome
</div>
```

So when this is executed, it automatically bind them together.

To understand how AngularJS routing works, have a look at AngularJS documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

and you'll see that, this:

```
$location.path('profile-01')
```

should be like:

```
$location.path('/profile-01')
```